# floatint point inaccuracy

Tags: c, floating-point, type-conversion, rounding

Mixing int and double produces a strange result in the following program:

```
int main()
{
    double x = 9.90, y = 10.0, z, w;
    int    ip, fp;

    z = y - x;

    ip = (int) z;

    w = (z - ip)*100;

    printf( "\nx = %f\ty = %f\tz = %f\tw = %f\n",
            x, y, z, w );

    printf("\nip = %d", ip); /* So far, so good */

    fp = (int) w; /* Why does fp get 9 and not 10??? */

    printf("\nfp = %d\n", fp);

    return 0;
}
```

Results:

```
x = 9.900000    y = 10.000000   z = 0.100000    w = 10.000000

ip = 0
fp = 9 (Should be 10!)
```

The results are the same using MingGW (WinXP) e Clang (MacOSX). Could anyone explain this strange behavior?

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html

Comment: it is being rounded down when converted to an int (technically truncated). The value will actually be 9.999999... due to floating point precision limitations. This is a common problem. Just round your number before converting, or add a tiny constant value.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, Dave. We know that floating point print outs are not WYSIWYG; e.g., w = 10.000000 doesn't mean that variable w holds 10.0 exactly. But how do we know that in fact it holds 9.9999... or something?

Comment: @user2234169: If `w` was >= 10.0 and < 11.0 then `fp` would've been 10. The fact that `fp` was 9 proves that `w` was >= 9.0 and < 10.0. The `printf` displayed `10.000000` for `w` which proves that `w` must be very close to 10. By combining both of these facts, you can determine that `w` must be less than 10 but very close to 10 (or "9.999999??????").

Comment: Change your `%f`'s to `%.21g`. Then you'll see what's going on.

Comment: @R.: That is not guaranteed by the C standard.

Comment: It's guaranteed by IEEE arithmetic.

Comment: @R.: The questioner has not indicated their C library conforms to IEEE 754. The OS X clang they are using should do the job correctly, if used with the libraries supplied by OS X. I do not know about MinGW.

Comment: My comment just shows a way to see what's going on; it's not a claim that all implementations must behave that way.

Comment: @R.: The problem is that, with an implementation that does not print floating-point values correctly, it causes more confusion.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you're essentially trying to do `w = 0.1 * 100`, and the value 0.1 can't be represented precisely by floating point (in the same way that `1/3` can't be represented precisely in decimal).

What you do get for 0.1 in binary is this:

```
0.00011001100110011001100110011001100110011001100110011001...
```

where the last 4 digits repeat forever.

A double doesn't have an infinite number of bits though, so it'd actually be:

```
1.100110011001100110011001100110011001100110011001100110 * 2**(-4)
```

where digits are discarded because they don't fit, starting with "01001001...". Because the discarded digits begin with a `0` the number would be rounded down. This means that you actually end up doing something like `w = 0.9999999999 * 100`.

Answer (score 0):

The error comes because a `double` can't exactly hold the value `9.9`.  The closest it can manage is actually `9.9000000000000003552713678800500929355621337890625`.  So your value for `w` is not `10`, its really `9.99999999999996447286321199499070644378662109375`.

When you use `%f` with printf, it rounds your values to 6 digits after the decimal.  If you change your printf formats to something like `%.60f`, you can see the full precision of your values.

Comment: `%.60f` will show the full precision plus a lot of noise.  Use with discretion.

Comment: @wallyk: `%.60f` **may** show the full precision. Some C implementations do not properly convert floating-point values to decimal, and the C standard does not require them to.